# Dropdown UL becomes transparent in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, transparent

I made a pretty standard CSS dropdown menu but something wierd is happening in IE.

As you can see in the screenshot it only shows the shadow and everything inside the element is transparent. I dont use transparancy anywhere on the website and the element shows correct in the other browsers.

[image: Transparent dropdown in IE]

Comment: Have you tried giving them `z-index` ?

Comment: Please share with us your code, a demo, and which version of IE you're having issues with.

Comment: Early IE has many problems, among which are the z-index/position/zoom. That's where I always look first. [`zoom: 1`](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1354-The-Power-Of-ZOOM-Fixing-CSS-Issues-In-Internet-Explorer.htm) will assign a `hasLayout` property to the element that will hopefully trigger and make it look decent. That's my best guess without looking at the code.

Comment: Please provide the code or add it in jfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out when you give an element a microsoft gradient filter it hides child elements that are outside the div. It all worked fine when i removed that piece of code.

On a side note, it also prevents border-radius from working in IE

The problem code:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#fafafa',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: I was running into the exact same issue. Just wanted to add that `overflow:visible` does not fix the issue. It also doesn't just pertain to the immediate parent. For example I had a "header" tag with the gradient, with a "nav" tag nested inside that, with my lists inside of that. This appears to be an issue with the core IE rendering engine in IE9 (and maybe below).